# Search page design with logical operators

Tags: gui-design, search, page-control

I have a page that displays a set of records. The page has filter section to search records.
[image]

currently the logical operator AND is applied between all the filter conditions. Now the requirement for including the OR operation has arisen. The user suggested to add a dropdown with AND,OR options next to Value dropdown. But the problem is operator precedence. If I am going to make the page to look like the image below, the user is definitely going to find it confusing and I am also not sure how to resolve this search.  [image]

Please suggest me how I could make this UI to let the user select the operator precedence easily.

Comment: I think the UI is self explanatory. In your example it is Case 1 && (Case 2 || Case 3 || Case 4) There is only one way to interpret that. However user might want much complex combination of operators. Agree with the accepted solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think in your situation using spacing to show groups would help understand the relation between elements. You could also add the functionality to drag elements around from a group to another and a remove button (this handlers could be placed on the left of each element permanent on touch devices or only on hover for mouse ones).

[image]

Comment: Good idea. I could apply the AND within a group.  Between groups the user can select the operator(AND | OR ) they want. Please confirm my understanding is right.

Comment: @Saranya yes, the idea is that between elements of the same group there is no need to display AND. In the buttons below, clicking AND would add an element to the last group, clicking OR would create an element in a new group. If you think there is need to create elements in "old" groups you could possibly include a button "Add a new element to this group" or similar.

Comment: @Saranya you are welcome; at least I hope it gives you some idea that helps you proceed with your scenario.

Comment: You should also consider allowing the user to add extra conditions in already completed groups

Comment: @Sebastianb thanks, yes you are right, I was commenting that above but I'll include it in the answer.